# Coin change with the type of specific coin as the returned value

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I need to write this function that calculates the minimum number of the coins to get the specified value.

the function as a parameter has a value (int) and an string the has information about the type of coin and its value (its a bit different from the classic version on coin change)

as an example :

`coin(20, "a:9,b:2,c:1");`

so i have the value 20. 
In this case I have the coin called 'a' with value of 9, coin 'b' with value of 2 and coin 'c' with value 1 
So this function at the end will return me 'aab' that meens that i used 2 time the coin 'a' and one time the coin 'b' which is minimum
Here are some othere test cases:

`assert(strcmp(coin(4, "a:5,b:2,c:1"),"bb")==0);
assert(strcmp(coin(12,"a:3,b:2"),"aaaa")==0);`

Hope someone can help me with this.
I already saw some example (http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/jeuR48) with same issue but i really dont have any idea how i can manage the type of coin

Comment: What do you mean by "manage type of coin". You need to parse the coinlist and either put it in an array or a list. You could first read the number of `,` in the list and allocate an array with `num_commas+1`, then parse the list (you have several functions for this, e.g. `strtok`).

Comment: Note that returning strings in C generally comes with some strings attached. Heh. In other words, you must think about the memory-management for the returned string.

Comment: and also add test cases that wont work with the "minimal approach" to this program (going from top down and substracting). Try this case: `coin(12,"a:10,b:8,c:4,d:1")`. This would give you 3 coins with the minimal approach (`add`), bot the correct answer is 2 coinds (`bc`).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in many ways. Here is one approach that might get you started.

Define a `struct` for holding the coin name and value:

```
struct CoinType
{
    char name;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

Then you need to parse the input string, i.e. split it into names and values and save it in an array for later use. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct CoinType
{
  char name;
  unsigned int value;
};

int getCoins(struct CoinType **ct, char* s)
{
  char *token;
  char name;
  unsigned int value;
  int n = 0;

  token = strtok(s, ",");
  while(token)
  {
    if (sscanf(token, "%c:%u", &name, &value) != 2)
    {
      // Illegal input
      exit(1);
    }

    *ct = realloc(*ct, (n+1)*sizeof(struct CoinType));
    if (*ct == NULL)
    {
      // Out of mem
      exit(1);
    }

    (*ct)[n].name = name;
    (*ct)[n].value = value;
    ++n;

    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
  }
  return n;
}

void printCoins(struct CoinType *ct, int n)
{
  int i;
  printf("Coins available:\n");
  for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    printf("name=%c with value=%u\n", ct[i].name, ct[i].value);
  }
}

void coin(unsigned int amount, char* s)
{
  struct CoinType *ct = NULL;
  int coins = getCoins(&ct, s);
  printCoins(ct, coins);

  // Add code to match a number of coins with amount

  // Clean up
  free(ct);
}

int main(void)
{
  char s[] = "a:9,b:2,c:1";
  coin(20, s);

  return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
Coins available:
name=a with value=9
name=b with value=2
name=c with value=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i still have some problem getting the rest of the code work
im usign this guid (https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Dynamic_Programming/Chapter_04_-_Minimum_no_of_coins_to_make_a_sum.jsp) to figure out what to do.
Not really sure how to find the size of the `char *s`  parameter of the coin function,can you please help me

Comment: @chux - thanks. For a moment I just forgot that realloc called with NULL is the same as malloc. Answer updated.

Comment: @totoro - why would you need the size of `char *s`? The code alreay handles that part.

Comment: Although `*ct = realloc(*ct, (n+1)*sizeof(struct CoinType));` is OK, consider `*ct = realloc(*ct, (n+1)*sizeof *(*ct));` which does not rely on explicitly coding the matching type .  easier to code, review, maintain.

Comment: The comment above is what im trying to do to get the minumum off coind and its type...not sure where im wrong